# How to access UI-SELECT Dropdown value [AngularJS 1.4.7]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I'm unable to access the selected dropdown value in UI-Select, How do I access the selected values in the controller?

```
<ui-select name="optionType" ng-model="optionType.selected" theme="bootstrap"  append-to-body="true" reset-search-input="true">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Option">
    <span ng-bind-html="ctrl.trustAsHtml($select.selected.type)"></span>
  </ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="option in optionTypes | filter: $select.search" position="down">
    <span ng-bind-html="ctrl.trustAsHtml(option.type) | highlight: $select.search"></span>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.optionType = {};

$scope.optionTypes =
  [
    {type: "Risk Reversal"},
    {type: "Straddle"},
    {type: "Strangle"},
    {type: "Spread"},
    {type: "VANILLA"}
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check their 'Object as source' [example](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/#examples)

You need to bind it to repeat like this:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="item.type as item in optionTypes">
```

Comment: How do you access the selected values in the controller though?

Comment: through ng-model, there you get entire selected object

Comment: Do you have a working plunker? I'm getting undefined when I console.log("optionType.selected")

Comment: don't have any, but this is the official one and it's exactly your case - http://plnkr.co/edit/ePktG1p8QCf0DbIlM03m?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

There I don't see a need of using `ng-bind-html` by looking at your dropwon collection. Although if you need it there make sure you have `trustAsHtml` function, inside your controller `$scope` and then use `trustAsHtml(selected.type)` instead of `ctrl.trustAsHtml(selected.type)`.

**Without `ng-bind-html`**

```
<ui-select name="optionType" ng-model="optionType.selected" theme="bootstrap" append-to-body="true" reset-search-input="true">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Option">
      <span ng-bind="$select.selected.type"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="option in optionTypes | filter: $select.search" position="down">
      <span ng-bind="option.type | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/N6LwbYmCYUC9tCYVPYvB?p=preview)